# How to check battery wear level in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, batterylevel

I have problem with check battery wear level like app Battery Life in App Store. So how to check battery wear level and fully charged battery in iOS 10 because IOKit private Apple's Framework removed many information in iOS 10 and I don't understand how to use IOKit to programing check information about system.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, do you need the phone battery?
If yes, you don't need `IOKit`. Just `UIDevice` which is part of `UIKit`.

```
let batteryLevel = UIDevice.current.batteryLevel * 100 //multiply by 100 to get percents
```

Comment: I want to check battery wear level and fully charged battery by mAh. Example fully charged battery my iphone current is 1700 mAh like information from Battery  Life.